# ¿Cómo hago para saltarme las rutas de wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Tengo Wordpress en la raíz root del sitio, creo una carpeta `/algo/mipagina.html` pero al entrar a la URL: `http://misitio.com/algo/mipagina.html`

Sale este error :

```
No Results Found
The page you requested could not be found. Try refining your search, or use the navigation above to locate the post.
```

Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Si no me equivoco creo que en Administración del sitio->Ajustes generales puedes modificar la ruta de tu wordpress.

Comment: Ya vi fue error mío por una mayúscula, no sabía que era case sensitive.